# Проблема с маршрутизацией

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2, yii, маршрутизация

Добрый день знатоки!

Есть один онлайн магазин. Он написан на yii первой редакции. Я сейчас работаю над новой версией магазина, но на движке yii2.

Суть проблемы в чем. У меня сильно сжаты сроки и поэтому админ часть и мобильная версия пока остались на старом движке, так как они неплохо работают.

Я объединил старый сайт и новый на одном хосте, поместив старый в подпапку /old/. Настроил маршрутизацию посредством htaccess таким образом, что при входе на www.example.com/old/ с десктопа - открывается админ часть. Если зайти с мобильного устройства на www.example.com, то происходит редирект на /old/, где подхватывается мобильная часть. Но есть одна важная проблема - такая реализация не годится для сео. Понятно, что такая реализация в корне неверна, но сейчас мне нужен костыль, который будет работать какое то время.

И вот сам вопрос - у кого-нибудь есть идея как можно реализовать работу мобильной версии без /old/ малой кровью? Может, какое-то правило для htaccess мне поможет? Можно, конечно, попытаться объединить оба проекта в одной директории - но тут будет много возни с именами директорий и файлов.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: а что если редирект с помощью htaccess заменить нормальным редиректом из yii?

Answer (score 0):

Звучит как хомяк, хомяк и в продакшн.
Организуйте себе тестовое окружение, разрабатывайте вторую версию там, а потом перенесите на хост.
Полагаю, что для админки можно сделать поддомен, а для мобильной версии используйте временный редирект (302). Обычно поисковики корректно обрабатывают такие решения.

Comment: Да, согласен, решение далеко от оптимального. Но, как я уже выразился - на данный момент у меня нет выхода. В планах перписать и мобилку и админ на новом движке, но сейчас нужно решить вопрос быстро и эфективно. Сейчас для мобильной версии используется редирект, но компания, которая занимается нашим СЕО - говорит, что это не подходит. Нужно что бы урлы у мобилы и десктопа совпадали.

Answer (score 0):

admin.mysite.com - тут админка на yii1

mysite.com - тут front на yii2

m.mysite.com - тут front мобильная версия на yii2 (хотя как по мне с помощью flex или bootstrap можно решить вопросы мобильной версии на том же домене, как-то попахивает 90-ми)

test.mysite.com - тут работает с новой админкой на yii2

шаблон yii2 естественно только advanced. B все будет работать и все будут счастливы.